# Is there an library to generate CRUD pages for Java EE Entities?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm currently looking at writing a Java EE app that has about 20 entities, with relations, that will require a whole set of boiler plate CRUD servlets (well, Spring MVC controllers) and JSP pages. These will be time consuming to write and maintain.

I'm tempted to learn ASM and roll my own, is there any good ways to generate avoid this work? I'd love to be able to define my entities, their relationships and constraints, and have a program do the work generating the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [JBoss Seam Forge project](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/FORGE/Home) for JavaEE/JPA CRUD pages generation.
But if You've an existing JPA project, You can use the [Metawidget project](http://metawidget.org/) to realize Your own simple one-page CRUD solution as I made for myself.

Answer (score 2):

With Telosys Tools you can generate this kind of CRUD pages 
( see the demo on line : http://bookstore-spring.telosys-tools-demo.cloudbees.net/ )

The simplest way is to follow this tutorial (for Spring MVC - Spring Data - JPA ) : 
https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/springmvc-jpa-springdatajpa

Answer (score 1):

- Spring Roo
- Grails
- AppFuse

Netbeans was able to do this at one point, not sure anymore

Answer (score 1):

You should seek for IDE features instead of Libraries. Oracle JDeveloper with ADF Components can do the work, and [Netbeans](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html) has a similar feature with JSF and JPA. You should give them a try.